# DNAT iptable rule does not create session

Tags: iptables

I have configured iptable rule (PREROUTING) to create DNAT. However, this is not working as expected, I could see these rules are hitting (iptables -vL -t nat) but nat session are not created ( conntrack -L). I don't see that packet in any tracepoints. It's being dropped silently by the kernel. How can we check what happens to the packet? Any logs can be helpful here?

Comment: Show us your rule set and your hit counts. Use tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) to observe raw packets coming and going, to help isolate to send or return path as the problem and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DougSmythies..It was due to martian packet. Below answer helped me to find out the root cause. Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see DNAT rules are hitting and there is no connection being created for that rule, then this could be due to martian packet drops. You can verify this by enabling martian logs on all interface.  Please have look at the following video which would help you to narrow down the issue further.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA9ik52N6AA

Comment: Thanks for your help ...It was due to martian packet drops ..Thanks a lot